# d3v5 manual zoom and wheel zoom are not in sync

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am using d3.js version 5, and added zoom to my main svg:

```
const zoom = window.d3.zoom().on('zoom', onZoom);
const svg = window.d3.select('#neo4j-graph')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', '100%')
        .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet')
        .call(zoom)
        .append('g');

function onZoom() {
    svg.attr('transform', window.d3.event.transform);
    currentScale = window.d3.event.transform.k;
}
```

also added a cool feature, that when clicking on one of the nodes, it center the view and zoom to it:

```
function centerToNode(d) {
        const scale = 1.5;

        // normalize for width/height
        let newX = width / 2 - scale * d.x;
        let newY = height / 2 - scale * d.y;
        let transform = window.d3.zoomIdentity.scale(scale).translate(newX, newY);
        svg.transition().duration(1000).call(zoom.transform, transform);

    }
```

both work great, however there is a small bug I can't fix, when I click on the node, the view zoom and center to it, and then when I use the wheel to zoom out from the node, the view "jumps" away to the previous position I was before the click. in other words looks like the manual zoom update the view but doesnt update the internal zoom values inside d3.

am I do it wrong? do I need a way to sync the manual zoom with the d3 zoom?
any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out, this code:

```
const svg = window.d3.select('#neo4j-graph')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet')
    .call(zoom)
    .append('g');
```

actually insets the 'g' element into the 'svg' variable, rather than the SVG element. that caused some mismatches later in the code.

so the new fixed code is:

```
const zoom = window.d3.zoom().on('zoom', onZoom);
const svg = window.d3.select('#neo4j-graph')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');

const g = svg.call(zoom).append('g');

function onZoom() {
    g.attr('transform', window.d3.event.transform);
}
```